# "python -m doctest" ignores files with same names in different directories

Tags: python, python-import, doctest

Suppose we have two files:

#### fail/stuff.py

```
"""
>>> True
False
"""
```

#### pass/stuff.py

```
"""
>>> True
True
"""
```

Then we run them both under doctest:

```
python -m doctest fail/stuff.py pass/stuff.py
```

As expected, we see an error from `fail/stuff.py`.  But if we run them in the opposite order:

```
python -m doctest pass/stuff.py fail/stuff.py
```

Then it passes!

Is there some fundamental reason why Python's import system is unable to cope with loading tests from both files, or is doctest simply broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some fundamental reason why Python's import system is unable to cope with loading tests from both files, or is doctest simply broken?

Doctests is basically just broken.  There's no fundamental reason why Python import system can't handle this scenario.  Ergo, there's no fundamental reason the test runner can't also handle this scenario.   I doubt they gave it too much thought when writing the command-line interface, because most people wouldn't use doctest as a runner directly (rather, integrating the library code in with a more full-featured runner and using a doctest plugin would be much more usual).

You can just use a better test runner.  For example, nose (amongst others) won't have this problem:

```
$ nosetests pass/stuff.py fail/stuff.py --with-doctest
.F
======================================================================
FAIL: Doctest: stuff
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/doctest.py", line 2199, in runTest
    raise self.failureException(self.format_failure(new.getvalue()))
AssertionError: Failed doctest test for stuff
  File "/private/tmp/fail/stuff.py", line 0, in stuff

----------------------------------------------------------------------
File "/private/tmp/fail/stuff.py", line 2, in stuff
Failed example:
    True
Expected:
    False
Got:
    True


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.004s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I added `-m $.` to the `nosetests` command to avoid having it run functions with "test" in their name (which are not actually tests in my project.  Other than that, this is a good solution.  And the parallel option of `nosetests` is nice too.

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one top-level module with the same name in a Python process, and `python -m doctest` treats all files passed to it as top-level modules. Importing `pass/stuff.py` fills an entry in the module cache for the `stuff` module, and when doctest tries to import the second file you specified, the import system finds the entry for `pass/stuff.py` instead of loading `fail/stuff.py`.

There are ways they could try to get around this. For example, it's possible to import a module from a file without filling in its `sys.modules` entry, but that might still fail if these identically-named files also have identically-named, distinct dependencies, or if any circular imports are involved. They could try rolling back `sys.modules` to a pre-test state after running a test, which would be more reliable but less efficient, and could still fail with modules that don't play well with reloading. Another option would be to spawn a separate subprocess for each test, which would be most reliable but least efficient.